# A problem with .NET 2.0 project, using a 3.0 DLL which implements WCF services

Tags: c#, wcf, frameworks, client, abstract

I made a client for accessing my WCF services in one project, and all classes that work with services inherit from this class:

```
public abstract class ServiceClient<TServiceClient> : IDisposable where TServiceClient : ICommunicationObject
```

This class is where I do stuff like disposing, logging when the client was called, etc. some common stuff which all service classes would normally do.

Everything worked fine, until I got the task to implement this on an old system. I got into a problem when I used this project (DLL) in an other project which cannot reference `System.ServiceModel` (since it's an old .NET 2.0 software that I still maintain, and upgrading it to 3.0 is out of the question). Here, if I omit `where TServiceClient : ICommunicationObject` then the project can build, but the `ServiceClient` cannot use, for example, `client.Close()` or `client.State`

So, is my only solution to drop the `where` statement, and rewrite the service classes?

Comment: What do you mean by "(since it's an old .NET 2.0 software that I still maintain, and upgrading it to 3.0 is out of the question)"?  Is it that the clients of your 2.0 app can't have .NET 3.0+ framework installed?  Or, is it that you can't open the 2.0 project in VS and recompile, targeting .NET 3.0+?  It might not involve any actual code changes to bring your old app from 2.0 to 3.0.

Comment: Well, the server has the newest framework installed, hence I'm able to import my DLL (which is precompiled -- I'm not allowed to add projects into the solution). And, there are many people working on the same project (yes, I mean project, not solution!), etc. I just can't upgrade it (as much as I wanted it, knowing this problem would be solved instantly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't upgrade that project to 3.0, this (or a wrapper class) seems to be your only option.

Comment: Hmm... I tried to wrap it a bit, making a simple static class with a static field that implement this class (inside that 3.0 project) but I'm still getting the same build error when i try to call any method use it in 2.0... I'm guessing if I were to implement all methods separately in static methods, it would work, but it kinda seems like a bad solution.

Comment: Well, in the end I just used `IDisposable`, instead of `ICommunicationObject` and rewritten some of the code -- though there is still a problem that I can't invoke the dispose directly (because it asks for 3.0 framework) but if i use the `using` statement, the client closes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What is stopping you upgrading? 3.0 is not really a new version of the framework, it is just some additional dll's. Your 2.0 code will run as before using the same .net libraries.

Comment: Unfortunately that 2.0 is not "my" code... it's a part of a huge software that manages international calls. Hence, I really don't have a say on how to code that, I just have to make adjustments for a small piece of that software.